# How to send the output of a AWS nodejs output to the browser rather than the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm writing up a nodejs application which should spit out the output to the screen rather than a console.log.

My code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'AK*************37D', secretAccessKey: 'DyP*****************************7THvRfro', region: 'ap-south-1'});
var http=require('http')
var server=http.createServer((function(request,response)
{
    response.writeHead(200,
    {"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
    response.end("Hello World\n");

// Create S3 service object
s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

//Call S3 to list the buckets
s3.listBuckets(function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data.Buckets);
  }
});

var params = { 

    Bucket: 'lfs-test-mb',
    Delimiter: '',
    //Prefix: 's/5469b2f5b4292d22522e84e0/ms.files' 
  }

  s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
    if(err)throw err;
    console.log(data);
  });

}));
server.listen(7000);
```

This code works perfectly and I'm able to run "http://localhost:7000" which returns the output to the terminal.

```
D:\AWS_NodeJS>node lfs.js
{
  IsTruncated: false,
  Marker: '',
  Contents: [
    {
      Key: '39e8e2ab94c5ca5388cecf49481a05738e1d6ceaf127a48202f2ea670f9755ec',
      LastModified: 2020-04-22T00:01:03.000Z,
      ETag: '"40a62c83b10fe56bc9894d60631992a5"',
      Size: 31457280,
      StorageClass: 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      Key: '4a474cd829d49e686e1a998b4700955e024a17e62d35eb576973429f9159f2e6',
      LastModified: 2020-04-24T04:56:32.000Z,
      ETag: '"eb0542a9e23c8bfcf756e747502722f4"',
      Size: 11690801,
      StorageClass: 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
      Owner: [Object]
    },
  ],
  Name: 'lfs-test-mb',
  Prefix: '',
  MaxKeys: 1000,
  CommonPrefixes: []
}
```

How can i send the response to the screen rather than the terminal????

Answer (score 0):

The console.log will print the message to terminal. If you want to display the message in browser, you should return the message by response.send(...) before response.end. Something like this:

```js
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
response.send(data.Buckets);
response.end();
```